# Adding additional meta-data to assets in Watson Knowledge Catalog

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

Currently, my understanding is that the Watson Knowledge Catalog only has options to add predefined meta-data for data assets, Is there any way to add additional meta-data via UI or APIs. Say If I add the additional meta-data via API, will it be searchable & exposed through the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional metadata to any assets or create custom asset types.  You do this via PUT /v2/asset_types/{type_name}.

Within the asset type, you can set whether any additional attributes or metadata are searchable or not.  Once you do, then any new assets of that asset type can be populated with those additional attributes and you can instantiate searches off that metadata.

The new asset type will appear in the UI; however the additional metadata will not appear.  This is an enhancement we are hoping to achieve in a foreseeable future.